# Routes rewritten for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
map.resources :users do |user|
user.resources :votes
user.resources :voteable do |mv|
mv.resources :votes
end 
end
```

would be this in rails 3 correct:

```
resources :users do
 resources :votes, :books do
  resources :votes

resources :books
resources :users
```

I checked here http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/ and on stackoverflow, but I just wanted to make sure. I am trying to get the thumbs up gem(vote_fu with some modifications) to work, and I think my issues are coming from the routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block would be in rails3:

```
resources :users do
  resources :votes
  resources :voteable do
    resources :votes
  end 
end
```

You were missing the `end` statements.